# How to import a project from repository for readthedocs?

Tags: git, git-clone, read-the-docs

I have a project on a `github` repository, and I'm trying to build a documentation for it, based on its markdown files. I decided to use `readthedocs` for it, however, I'm having trouble importing it correctly. While trying to build the docs, it returns the following error message:

```
checkout
-----

Failed to import project; skipping build.

Error
-----

Failed to get code from 'http://myurl/myrepo.git' (git clone): 128
```

The address I provide is public, not SSH or anything. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried  `https://myurl/myrepo.git`?

Comment: Well I guess you could provide real log to help us answer your question. :-)